# What is the proper usage of a constructor when instantiating in the main class?

Tags: java, constructor

The way my teacher writes and organizes code is very different than what is proposed in my supplementary textbook. In a recent lab, we were required to use the `wheels` library to display several objects in a single window. Here is the `Snowman` class that was written by my teacher (code for other objects have not been included for convenience):

```
public class Snowman {
    private Ellipse _top;
    private Ellipse _middle;
    private Ellipse _bottom;

public Snowman() {
        _top = new Ellipse();
        _top.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        _top.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
        _top.setFrameThickness(1);
        _top.setSize(80, 80);
        _middle = new Ellipse();
        _middle.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        _middle.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
        _middle.setFrameThickness(1);
        _middle.setSize(120, 120);
        _bottom = new Ellipse();
        _bottom.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        _bottom.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
        _bottom.setFrameThickness(1);
        _bottom.setSize(160, 160);
    }
    public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
        _top.setLocation(x + 40, y - 170);
        _middle.setLocation(x + 20, y - 100);
        _bottom.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

This object, among others, is later instantiated in the `SnowmanCartoon` class:

```
public class SnowmanCartoon extends Frame{
    private Snowman _snowman;
    private Eyes _eyes;
    private Hat _hat;
    private Bubble _bubble;

    public SnowmanCartoon() {
        _snowman = new Snowman();
        _snowman.setLocation(100, 300);
        _eyes = new Eyes();
        _eyes.setLocation(165, 150);        
        _hat = new Hat();
        _hat.setLocation(152, 98);
        _bubble = new Bubble();
        _bubble.setLocation(280, 60);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SnowmanCartoon();
    }
}
```

---

Here are my concerns:

1. In both of these classes, why is there a method of the same name as the class, and what is its purpose?
2. Why is the method `setLocation()` a void method while the method `Snowman()` is not, even though `Snowman()` does not return anything?
3. In the `SnowmanCartoon` class, when it says `private Snowman _snowman;` and `_snowman = new Snowman();`, is `Snowman` referring to the `Snowman` class, or rather the `Snowman()` method?
4. If the instantiation of the `Snowman` object is referring to the `Snowman()` method to set all of its properties, why don't I need to use the dot operator: `Snowman.Snowman()`?
5. In my textbook, instance variables and methods are declared in a one class and are instantiated in another. However, they seem to occur simultaneously in my teacher's code.

Comment: Some times when you have to read you have to read.

Comment: Not sure why people down voted you for not understanding a constructor. You're putting in effort to learn and that in my opinion is much better than those who post just for answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method that is named the same as a class is called "constructor" of the class. It is used to instantiate an object.

Example:

```
public class MyClass { // class
    public MyClass() { // constructor

    }
}
```

Note that constructor is just like any other method, however, it does not have a return type. It basically returns "this" object.

When you call

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
```

this will actually invoke the constructor and create the object.

Note that you can have multiple constructors in a class by using different number and types of parameters.

In java, if you do not include any constructor, then any class will by default have the default parameterless constructor.

```
public MyClass() {
}
```

Tons of information available on constructors online. They are the basic concepts to start learning object oriented programming. Some more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

--EDIT--
answering question about how to call specific question.

Take these two constructors

```
public MyClass(){
// do things
}

public MyClass(String p){
// do things
}
```

Then when you instantiate object

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(); // use constructor 1
MyClass d = new MyClass("value"); // use constructor 2
```

Comment: In the `SnowmanCartoon` class, assuming I had multiple constructors in the `Snowman` class, how would I use a specific constructor as opposed to another?

Comment: @AbdullahFahad You can call a specific constructor by specifying the particular parameters that the constructor is defined with. see Edit..

Answer (score 6):

`public Snowman() {...}` is called as constructor. This will be invoked while you are creating object for this class. If you don't define a constructor, jvm implicitly creates one for you. Please read this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to understand more about constructors.

`Snowman()` is not a method, it is constructor. constructor don't have return type. If you add return type it would be treated as method.

Comment: That clears up several things for me. Thank you! Could you explain a bit more on constructors? The formal definitions I have found do not come intuitively for me.

Comment: @AbdullahFahad: Updated answer with good resource to understand constructors.

Comment: ...ctors are methods, just without an explicit return type and cannot be invoked without `new`, at least in Java...

Answer (score 4):

> In both of these classes, why is there a "method" of the same name as
>   the class?

This kind of method is called a constructor. If it takes no parameters, it is then know as the "default constructor". Constructors are what you use to build your instances ie. `Snowman s = new Snowman();` calls the default constructor.

> Why is the method setLocation a void method, but Snowman not one, even
>   though it does not return anything?

Because constructors are different than normal methods. They return an instance of their Object ie `new Snowman()` returns a new instance of Snowman with in its default state.

> In the main SnowmanCartoon class, when it says private Snowman
>   _snowman; and _snowman = new Snowman();, is it referring to the Snowman class, or rather the Snowman() method?

If you ever see `new Snowman()` (or any equivalent), that's always referring to the constructor.

> Since that is the case, why don't I need to run Snowman.Snowman() to
>   set all the properties, since it is a method, and not public static
>   void main?

When you run your program, you aren't running your classes. You're instantiating instances of your Objects to use with other operations. Saying `Snowman s = new Snowman()` leaves you with a `Snowman` Object named `s` so that you can now do things with that Object.

> In Head First Java, instance variables and methods are declared in a
>   separate class, while they are instantiated in a separate class. Here,
>   this seems to happen at the same time, but I do not understand how.

This question doesn't make much sense to me.

> In the main class, when I create a new SnowmanCartoon, why don't I
>   need to do something to launch it, like create the window, etc.?

This is because that class is extending `Frame`. `Frame` has default operations that are used by the base class (`SnowmanCartoon`). So in short your super class is taking care of this for you.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) in java. This method is called when you do

```
Snowman s = new Snowman();
```

Answer (score 2):

1 It's not a method, it's a constructor.

2 void is just a return type. void means the method does not return anything. And constructors do not have returns.

3 It's refering to Snowman() constructor. It's not a method. It creates a snowman object.

5 You can put the instantiation of snowman object in a different class. I guess your teacher put it in the same class for simplicity.

6 I am assuming JVM takes care of it.